# use namespace as type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have installed type definitions for google maps that declares a namespace like this:

```
namespace google.maps {
  export class Map {
    // ...
  }

  // ...
}
```

So if i just use the API globally it works beautifully:

```
const map = new google.maps.Map();
```

For unit testablity I don't want to access the API globally but instead inject it. But it seems I can't type that a variable should by from type `google.map`

So this doesn't work:

```
function mapFactory(api: google.maps) {
    return new api.Map();
}
```

Any solution how to use the namespace as a type?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Try:

```
function mapFactory(api: typeof google.maps) {
    return new api.Map();
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why it works or refer to the docs? I didn't see it in docs and don't understand why `typeof` can be used with namespace.

Comment: @Sergey there's a bit about it here: [Optional Module Loading and Other Advanced Loading Scenarios](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#optional-module-loading-and-other-advanced-loading-scenarios): "To maintain type safety, we can use the typeof keyword. The typeof keyword, when used in a type position, produces the type of a value, in this case the type of the module"