# How to reference namespace as Type in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps

`google-map-react` loads google-map library for me. But loaded library has no type information.
It just returns it as `any`, as follows.

```
function onLoadGoogleMap(): { maps: any } {
    return {
        maps: google.maps
    }
}
```

So I installed `@types/googlemaps` on my own. Then I wanted to set type information to it like this. But it gives me the error of `Namespace 'google' has no exported member 'maps'.`

```
function main() {
    // maps is loaded as any
    const { maps } = onLoadGoogleMap()
    // I want type information, BUT this show me a error.
    const googleMaps: {
        maps: google.maps
    } = {
        maps: maps,
    }

    new googleMaps.maps.LatLng(12, 32)
}
```

I found out what `@types/googlemaps` looks like. It's similar to this.

```
declare namespace google.maps {
    class LatLng {
        constructor(lat: number, lng: number)
    }
}
```

How can I set type information of namespace?
Playground is here.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?jsx=2#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA7KBbEBnADlMCDmA9gXhCAHQpSbrwDeAsAFDwvyRTo0AyUALl4jx0mrUWwKJ0vGAFcwvAjAAU0XgC4kMlACMQMADTwIgjYi26YAShGsAvk3uMmAMxmJ5ASwnwJXAlGAAcSISEABZKiVLDVp4SmoNKEQAT3hbYWZWOF4ZGEQMsVZ49A1CYlIKKnQbFkdHFzdPb0oPRCiC1gB6Triq+A8aCH9QYHgOMZSa8UleOl7qNPgAXh9EPwDg8vDI60yWbvgASXgAdyTZ3mTMBFbnRUpeL0QpsAkpeDLQiISOwuLSkIVYpTdIrBh7MT-ebofQgphTRAgE4fQHbaiVdE8fiCJQARgATIYAMz43aOIA)

Thank you for your reading.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this question: [use namespace as type in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815932/use-namespace-as-type-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to solve this.

`@types/googlemaps` is a set of definitions, but namespace in typescript is much more like object.
[This post](https://michelenasti.com/2019/01/23/is-typescript-namespace-feature-deprecated.html) is a good reasource to know what namespace is in typescript.

So we can reference namespace type using `typeof` keyword as follows.

```
const googleMaps: {
    maps: typeof google.maps
} = {
    maps: maps,
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?jsx=2&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA7KBbEBnADlMCDmA9gXhCAHQpSbrwDeAsAFDwvyRTo0AyUALl4jx0mrUWwKJ0vGAFcwvAjAAU0XgC4kMlACMQMADTwIgjYi26YAShGsAvk3uMmAMxmJ5ASwnwJXAlGAAcSISEABZKiVLDVp4SmoNKEQAT3hbYWZWOF4ZGEQMsVZ49A1CYlIKKnQbFkdHFzdPb0oPRCiC1gB6Triq+A8aCH9QYHgOMZSa8UleOl7qNPgAXh9EPwDg8vDI60yWbvgASXgAdyTZ3mTMBFbnRUpeL0QpsAkpeDLQiISOwuKNS7XAjOD4hCrFKbpFYMPZif7zdD6SFMKaIEAnUFbb7oSrUMg8fiCJQARgATIYAMyk3aOIA)